# sizeof() raise errors with array

Tags: php

I've array and try to refer it in function like :

```
 function merge_ids(&$s_prod_ids){
    if (sizeof($s_prod_ids) > 1){
        $l=0;
        $r=sizeof($s_prod_ids)-1;
        $mid = sizeof($s_prod_ids)/2;
        $L=$mid-$l+1;
        $R=$r-$mid;
        $this->merge_ids($L);
        $this->merge_ids($R);
        $left_first=0;
        $right_first=0;
        $main=0;
        while (sizeof($L) > $left_first && sizeof($R) > $right_first){
            if ($L[$left_first] < $R[$right_first]){
                $s_prod_ids[$main] = $L[$left_first];
                $left_first++;
            }else{
                $s_prod_ids[$main]=$R[$right_first];
            }
            $main++;
        }
        while ($left_first < sizeof($L)){
            $s_prod_ids[$main] = $L[$left_first];
            $left_first++;
            $main++;
        }
        while ($right_first < sizeof($R)){
            $s_prod_ids[$main] = $R[$right_first];
            $right_first++;
            $main++;
        }
    }

}

public function index()
{
    $alg = new SliderController();
    $s_prod_ids = array(1,2,3,4 ...)
    $alg->merge_ids($s_prod_ids)
```

But `sizeof` raise error and says that sizeof parameter MUST be array. I checked it with `dd()` and `merge_ids` gets array but for `sizeof` not working. Can someone say what I don't do correctly in php?

Comment: dd output would be helpful to debug this.

Comment: Here, I see you try to use merge sort? yes?

Comment: Yes i try to use merge sort to sort ids

Comment: You should have problem in recurse can you show full code please?

Comment: This may occur if ` $s_prod_ids` is not an array. can you try `gettype($s_prod_ids)` and check the type of the variable

Comment: I checked it with dd() and it's array

Comment: Please show us your _actual_ code copy/pasted directly from your editor instead of some shorthand reproduction of it.

Comment: Now show us the full and actual error message, including line number (and point out that line in your code).  You are using `sizeof()` multiple places in your code.

Comment: `sizeof($L)` `$L` is NOT an array, look at the code above it, NOT IS `$R`

Answer (score 0):

At first `s_prod_ids` get arrays but, next when you are using recursion refer it `int` so, change your `$L` AND `$R` like this :

```
$L = array_slice($s_prod_ids, 0, $mid);
$R = array_slice($s_prod_ids, $mid);
```

Now you're slicing your ids